# Etymology of the word "broker"

Tags: etymology, idiom-requests, finance

I’ve had this personal hypothesis in the back of my mind for many years now about the etymology of the word “broker”.

I have gathered a few pieces of the puzzle (many of them in French and a few of them in English) but I have no firm evidence to back it.

Now that I've come across EL&U, with its high concentration of English Language enthusiasts of all horizons, I’d like to request some assistance, especially regarding the English side of the story.

Many English etymological dictionaries qualify the origin of “broker” as uncertain, and others are just content with mentioning immediate ancestors of the modern word.  But there is possibly a more captivating story to this particular word.

In my opinion *broker* comes from *brooch*/*broach*.  Here is why.

- In French the word for “broche”
  covers 2 English words: “brooch” (the
  jewel) and “broach” (roasting spit). 
  In a larger sense, a “broche” is any
  spiky tool used for piercing.
- One of these broaches, shaped like a
  “T”, with a drill-bit like end, was
  used during wine auctions to pierce
  sample barrels so that potential
  buyers could taste the wine and make
  their best buying offer according to
  the quality of the beverage.
- Incidentally the French term for the
  pitcher that would be placed below
  the subsequently inserted tap is
  “broc” [(nb, origin: uncertain in the
  wiktionary
  entry)](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/broc).
- Also well documented is the fact that
  the person in charge of piercing the
  hole is the “brocheur” (or
  “broceur”).

My conjecture is that this man was also in charge of the auction, hence the “broker”.  He would serve as a “broker” between the seller and the buyers.  Although it seems logical, I've found this explanation nowhere.

**So my questions are:**

1. Could you please provide some English words, idioms, citations or
   reference that could possibly back
   this conjecture?
2. Or do we have an altogether
   completely different etymology, I might have missed ?

That's the main question.  However I have also a couple of secondary requests, that could actually help reaching a conclusion.

3. I’ve also tried to find some genre
   paintings (in the taste of
   Netherlands Golden Age genre
   paintings) but with no success so
   far.
4. Also of interest would be to know
   whether there were English wine
   brokers (medieval England had a lot
   of vineyards) or whether the
   “broker” meaning was imported from
   the French “brocheur”, in which case
   one would have to admit that this
   meaning was lost, since French eventually
   borrowed the English word.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looking in the OED, I see support for the wine-cask-piercing tool origin, but not for the origin clearly involving one in charge of an auction.  There is a connection to wine selling, and this might be close to what you are theorizing.

> Etymology:  Middle English brocor,
> -our, brokour, < Anglo-Norman brocour (also broggour) = Old Northern French
> brokeor ( < Latin type *broccātōrem),
> nominative brokiere ( < Latin
> *broccātor) of which Godefroy has one example explained by him as ‘celui qui
> vend du vin au broc’, as to the
> precise sense of which see below. The
> Central French equivalent was
> brocheor, brochière; and the word is
> the agent noun of the Old French vb.
> brochier, Old Northern French brokier
> ( < Latin *broccāre) in the sense ‘to
> broach’ or ‘tap’ a cask. Brocheor,
> brokeor stand in precisely the same
> relation to the n. broche, broc, and
> the vb. brochier, brokier, as tapster
> or rather the earlier tapper stand to
> the n. tap, and vb. to tap in
> Teutonic: the brocheor, brokeor,
> brokour, or broker, was lit. a
> tapster, who retailed wine ‘from the
> tap’, and hence, by extension, any
> retail-dealer, one who bought to sell
> over again, a second-hand dealer, or
> who bought for another, hence a
> jobber, middleman, agent, etc. Compare
> sense of Latin caupo.
>
> The Romanic vb. broccare was evidently
> < brocco, brocca in the sense of
> ‘spike, piercing instrument’ ( < Latin
> broccus, brocca adj.: see broach n.1).
> But these nouns appear to have
> afterwards had their sense modified
> from the verb, so that in the Old
> French vendre à broke, or à broche, in
> modern French vendre à broc, the sense
> passed from ‘broach’, to ‘broaching,
> tapping’, and at length to ‘the
> quantity of wine drawn at a broaching
> or tapping’, and hence ‘the jug or
> vessel which held this’, as in modern
> French broc (from 5 to 10 litres).
> Anglo-Norman had also a derivative
> form abrocour, and there were
> Anglo-Latin words abrocator,
> abrocamentum; also brocarius
> ‘proxeneta, interpres et consiliarius
> contractuum’, and abrocarius.
> Brocarius appears to have been formed
> on the n. (broc(c)a, broc(c)us);
> abrocarius must have been formed on
> the apparent analogy of brocator,
> abrocator.

The earliest usages have already lost any connection to wine tapping or selling.

> 1377    Langland *Piers Plowman* B. v.
> 130   Amonges Burgeyses haue I be
> dwellynge at Londoun, And gert
> bakbitinge be a brocoure [C. brocor]
> to blame mennes ware.
>
> 1393    Langland *Piers Plowman* C. vii.
> 95   Ȝut am ich brocor of bakbytynge ·
> and blame mennes ware.
>
> 1582    R. Stanyhurst tr. Virgil *First Foure Bookes Æneis* i. 14   For gould his
> carcasse was sold by the broker
> Achilles.

Comment: Yes, it looks like another possible explanations was actually reselling in smaller quantities.

Comment: I eventually got access to the full OED and I'm amazed at the wealth of detail it has on that single word.  As you point out, the bottom line seems to be that reselling in smaller quantities preceded the modern sense of middle man in brokerage. So it has noting to do with auction as I initially thought.

Comment: @alain -- yes, great resource, if often overwhelming!  I'm glad you got to the bottom of it....

Comment: I like the now-lost wine reselling thought. In the Jesse Livermore autobiography, "Reminiscences of a Stock Operator," he describes the beginning of his career at bucket shops, where they would sell stocks or commodities in smaller quantities (like 5 shares or a fraction of a sugar contract).

Answer (score 2):

[etymonline](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=broker) is not very definitive, but ascribes most likely to Old French *brochier*. I would then assume that this comes from the same etymology as *broche*, which is from Latin *brocchus* (as indicated in my *[Littré](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dictionnaire_de_la_langue_fran%C3%A7aise)*). *Broker* would thus share, though by different means, the etymology of *broach*.

Answer (score 2):

### References

Etymonline dates  *broker* late 14c, and adds:

> *broc* meant in addition to "that which breaks," "affliction, misery."

Opinions seem to be divided on the exact meaning of *broker*. Some etymologists believe that the expression is derived from the Anglo Norman *brokour* meaning "small trader". However, others claim it is derived from the Anglo-Saxon *brocour*, meaning "tapster", which in turn came from the Latin *broccus*, "protecting". Thus someone who used a projecting device to obtain wine samples for examination was called a *brocour* (or broker).

- 1) According to *The Farlex Trivia Dictionary*, originally a *[broker](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Money+broker)*  was a person who bought wine cheaply in quantity and sold it at a profit; a *broker* came to mean any retailer who did this, or a middleman/agent.

This is also confirmed in a book proudly titled: *Now You Know Almost Everything: The Book of Answers*
 By Doug Lennox  (2005) It also states that *Brocour* first appeared in English **1377** in William Langland's narrative poem called

- 2) *[Piers Plowmman](http://books.google.it/books?id=eaAuAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA300&dq=middle%20english%20dictionary%20brocour&hl=en&sa=X&ei=qidvVOioB-fXyQPVkoAo&ved=0CDcQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=brocour&f=false)*:

  > I haue lent lordes and ladyes my chaffare
  >   And been her **brocour** after, and boughte it myself.
  >   Eschaunges and chevesances, with such chaffare I dele,
  >   And lene folke that lese wol a lyppe at every noble.

Yet the following terms *chaffare* (merchandise); *eschanges and chevesances* (barter and loans); *dele* (deal); *lene* (lend); and *lese wol a lyppe at* (will lose a part of gold); do not suggest that the **brocour** was a wine trader or merchant. Wine spelled *wyn* in Middle English is indeed mentioned in *Piers Plowmman* but I could find none which specifically referred to the piercing of wine barrels or the trading of this beverage.

- 3) I found a 15th century instance in a [Middle English Dictionary](http://books.google.it/books?id=4qv_Y-me2vQC&pg=PA873&dq=brocour&hl=en&sa=X&ei=OOZuVKH2B-WgyAPah4K4AQ&redir_esc=y#v=onepage&q=brocour&f=false)
  by Hans Kurath (1971)

> (1418) Grocer Lond.123: *That noon Alyon Strav[n]ger or englyssh
>   **Brocour** be resseyued in to the hoole Clothynge of the Feleshepe, of
>   lesse than he be admitted thereto at a Qvarter day*

- 4) In an 18th century *Complete Dictionary of the Arts and Sciences* (**1766**) the authors take care in defining the term accurately

> [BROKER](http://books.google.it/books?id=k5jcid_fsa4C&pg=RA1-PT307&dq=middle%20english%20broker&hl=en&sa=X&ei=UzVvVPKpJuTQygPrzoHYBQ&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAQ#v=onepage&q=middle%20english%20broker&f=false): a name given to persons of several and very different professions, the
>   chief of which are exchange brokers, stock-brokers, pawn-brokers, and
>   brokers, simply so called, who sell household furniture and
>   second-hand apparel

No mention, unfortunately, of wine traders or brokers.

- 6) But perhaps the most relevant reference I found which fails to confirm (but neither disproves) the OP's conjecture is taken from a volume of Parliamentary acts and bills titled verbatim: *Volume the Fifth of the Rolls of Parliament contains of the reign of Henry Sixth*
  Henry VI born in 1421, ruled England from **1422 to 1461** and was King of France until 1453

[image: 15th c. English Parliament, containing several instances of the expression "brocour"]

---

### idiom

Meanwhile, the OED reports that the expression *broken*, meaning to have no money, is dated 1593 and defines it as *Reduced or shattered in worldly estate, financially ruined; having failed in business, bankrupt*.

- The idiom *to be broke*  is from **1716**.

If a *broker* is someone who handles other people's money, it makes sense that *to be broke* means to be penniless. On a website called [Etymologically Speaking](http://www.westegg.com/etymology/), I found the following explanation for *broke* which, once again, is completely unrelated to a wine auctioneer or bidder.

> **Broke** (In the sense of having no money)
>   Many banks in post-Renaissance Europe issued small, porcelain "borrower's tiles" to
>   their creditworthy customers. Like credit cards, these tiles were
>   imprinted with the owner's name, his credit limit, and the name of the
>   bank. Each time the customer wanted to borrow money, he had to present
>   the tile to the bank teller, who would compare the imprinted credit
>   limit with how much the customer had already borrowed. If the borrower
>   were past the limit, the teller "broke" the tile on the spot.

<sub><sup>Source for OED citation: [What is the origin of the expression “I'm broke”?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/66746/what-is-the-origin-of-the-expression-im-broke/66761#66761)</sup></sub>

---

### etymology

In *A Glossary and Etymological Dictionary of Obsolete and Uncommon Words...* by William Toone (1834) I found the following entry which suggests that the term *broker* was used to mean an intermediary for different types of transactions. The entry  refers to a ***marriage broker***, once known as a *matchmaker*, but nowadays what we would call *online dating*, the world renown agency *Match.com* is a prime example. The term *broker* is said to derive from Old French *broggour*

[image: snippet taken from dict. entry: "broker"]

Answer (score 1):

I think it's probably instructive to think of the word *broach* meaning to "raise (a sensitive or difficult subject) for discussion", which is an alternate (and these days preferred) meaning of the word and therefore comes from the same etymology as that of piercing a cask to draw liquor.

From NOAD:

> ORIGIN Middle English : from Old French *brochier*, based on Latin *brocchus*, *broccus* ‘projecting.’ The earliest recorded sense was [prick with spurs,] part of the general meaning [pierce with something sharp,] from which sense 2 arose in late Middle English . Sense 1, a figurative use of this, dates from the late 16th cent.

This feels to me like what a broker does more than tapping a keg. The sense may be more of opening, starting, raising, or getting something going instead of pricking with a tool (even though that is the inspiration). It is in the transition to the figurative usage that I think *broker* resides. That is, if I understand your question completely.

Comment: +1.  I knew this idiomatic expression and actually found it quite puzzling.  In the context of starting a heated discussion about quality and price, this makes more sense indeed (regardless of whether the brokered commodity is wine or something else actually). Thx, makes more sense like this.

Answer (score 1):

Over three years after the question was raised I come across this interesting site, and I wanted to add that here in Spain many people think there might be a connection of the term *broker* with the Spanish *alboroque*. This word, from Arabic *burûk* (present, gratuity), with the article *al-*, and this related to *báraka* (luck, opportunity), in turn from *beraká* (blessing), was used to refer to a gift, a tip or a small feast given by dealers or individuals to a middleperson who had helped in a deal. The word in this meaning seems to be documented since the late 10th century. Apparently it was occasionally used to refer to the person, the agent himself, in which meaning it may be related to the Old Provençal *abrocador* (second-hand dealer, pedlar) and later Anglo-Norman *abrokour/brocour*. It also appears in Portuguese *alborcar* (to trade). 
I'm not saying that *broker* comes from Arabic through Spanish, but a relation between the terms seems very likely.

Answer (score 0):

My opinion; "banker and broker" is readily derived from Norse blacksmith-god Brokkr. The smithy makes the coin money (silver and gold typical) before it can be spent, aye? Vikings were good at plunder like gold being highly praised. Blacksmiths are typically "wolf-tribe" folks too - in my opinion. Later "Old English" as I think I'm typing British herein, not necessarily "English", but the Vikings wrote the saga "Beowulf" using Old English (Old Low German) on British soil. Certainly holds the 10th cent. AD and the Viking Age. Much earlier than the definitions proposed I've come across yet.

The words "dog" (think wolf or hound) and "bird" have no etymology in modern English (British). Vikings brought "Old English" to Britain and oldest coins made by Eceni or Iceni of Norfolk, England and dates ~200 BC. Similar to oldest Old English script on record. Vikings wrote the saga "Beowulf" on British soil. Iceni coins have wolf, or, the "Hounds of Heaven" on some types. They mimic Keltic style.

I'm Czech/Bohemian but also of Swedish-Vendel Era settlement as Jomsvikings of Wendland and Rugen Isle near their Jomsborg settlement (ref king Burislav) now Germany. This is why I'm blond and blue-eyes and yDNA R1a1. The river here on South Baltic goes due south to downtown Prague Square, too.

For Britain, the blacksmith is "Weyland Smithy" near Uffington (wolf-town?) S. Mercia region. I suggest the chalk White Horse on the hill near Weyland Smithy's hill and dolmen stones, is actually a running-wolf - my current opinion none-the-less.

It was Brokkr and his underworld dwarf buddy that created Thor's hammer. Key mythical blacksmiths always have dwarves, pygmy, or little people helpers, just like Santa's helpers on the North Pole, aye.

A pawn shop of Italy used 3 pellets, or 3 balls in a triangle on the shop sign so you would know its a pawn business. Some coins, crests, and scepters have this triad, too.

I'm suggesting you need to have money before you can bank it or barter it as a broker does today.

See Medici family (Italy) banking insignias from his timeline. I'm surprised it hasn't been mentioned but I've had my theory for a long time, like 30 years. But then again I'm freelance on these types of studies. I'm not in it for the money and I'm not a linguist either. Seems everyone is stuck including the linguist?

Look at modern pawn shop signs, 3 balls?

The modern "dollar bill" USA backs the World Bank currently. Think "Silver Dollar" coin. The original coin is Astro-Bohemian and called a "Joachimsthal" (St. Joachim - Joseph - some coins with Mary and baby Jesus). Goes back to about 1480 AD. In Bohemia, silver was mined and a highland city and mint was called Jachymov now UNESCO protected. By slang coin was called thaler, taller...dollar which means valley of thal.
The brothers as Counts of Schlik (Slik, Schlick) started these mines in Bohemia. A lot of currency names today is derived from here. Schlik's armoral has 3 balls on the coins, too. Family names also on coins. Later, Habsburg crown in Prague nationalized the coins, and put mint dates on them, too.

I don't think linguistics alone can solve the many questions. I'm okay with Norse blacksmith Brokkr for now.

Well, now that the cats out of the bottle, everybody can beat me up really good. I do have more ammo yet! [West Slavic-Saxons] Anglo-Saxon is Angles, Anglia, England, and English + Saxons (Germans). GGG guy, Grand Global Genome - my pen name.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).