# What is the origin of the expression "I'm broke"?

Tags: etymology

When people have no money with them they usually use the expression *"I'm broke"*

Does anyone know how this originated?

Comment: I don't know, but I can speculate that it's related to bankrupt, or "broken table". See here: http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=bankrupt

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Broke* is an old form, and nowadays informal, use of *broken*. If we look in the OED we can see that one of the meanings of *break* is:

> 11a. To ruin financially, make bankrupt (a person or bank).

[First recorded in the 17th century.]

> 11b. To become bankrupt, to ‘fail’ (commercially).

[First recorded in Shakespeare (*Merchant of Venice* Act III, sc.1).]

> he cannot choose but break.

The definition of *broken* with the meaning of *having no money* in the OED is:

> Reduced or shattered in worldly estate, financially ruined; having
>   failed in business, bankrupt.

[First occurrence of *broken* in this sense is recorded in 1593.]

> (Shakes. Rich. II, ii. i. 257 The Kings growne bankrupt like a broken
>   man.)

The first occurrence of *broke* is recorded in 1665:

> (Pepys Diary 6 July (1895) V. 6 It seems some of his creditors have
>   taken notice of it, and he was like to be broke yesterday in his
>   absence.)

Comment: Can you link to or provide the text of the earlier occurrences--especially the _Merchant of Venice_?

Comment: @Callithumpian: no access to OED online but Shakespeare's quotes are all easily available on the web. I've added the one to the *Merchant of Venice*.

Comment: Pepys' Diary covers 1660 to 1669 (consistent with 1665); why does the quote show "(1895)"?

Comment: @jwpat7: The *OED* shows the date of publication of the edition quoted, where it is significantly different from the date of composition. Pepys wrote his diary in a private shorthand that was not decoded until the 19th century. The edition referred to must be the one by Henry Wheatley published in 1893–9. (The online *OED* now refers to the 1972–83 edition by Latham and Matthews.)

Answer (score 2):

I suggest you check the expression [here](http://www.etymonline.com/) and you will get the following result:

*past tense and obsolete pp. of break (variant of broken); extension to "insolvent" is first recorded 1716 (broken, in this sense, is attested from 1590s). By coincidence, O.E. cognate broc meant, in addition to "that which breaks," "affliction, misery;" but that sense died out long before the current one began.*